# Graphing Activity budges that will also incorporate behavior

Tags: r, matlab, behavior, graphing

I have been given a challenging problem and was hoping for some recommendations.
I have activity data that I would like to display graphically and am looking for a package or program that could be used to solve my problem (preferably R).

The data is count of movements (`Activity`) collected hourly (`Time of day`) for 3 weeks (`Calendar Date`) or more with associated variables (`Food`/`Vegetation`).

Typically, as Ive been told the data can be processed and graphed in a program called *Clocklab* that is a Matlab product.  However, the added complication is the desire to plot this data according to a classification of feeding groups.  I was trying to find an equitable program/package in R for this but have come up short.

What the data looks like is simply:

```
Activity     time of day      Food type         Calendar Date
       0           01:00              B            03/24/2007
      13           02:00            ---            03/24/2007
       0           03:00              B            03/24/2007
       0           04:00              B            03/24/2007
       :               :              :                     :
    1246           18:00              C            03/24/2007
    3423           19:00              C            03/24/2007
       :               :              :                     :
       0           00:00            ---            03/25/2007
```

This data is circadian, circular, activity budgeting and I would like to have a graph that may be 3-D in nature that will show the diet selection and how much activity is associated with that diet plotted over time for multiple days/weeks.  I would do this by individual and then at a population level.  Ive a link to the program and example plot of what is typically produced by the program [Clocklab](http://www.actimetrics.com/ClockLab/).

Comment: This sounds interesting, but you will get much better recommendations if you provide a minimal producible set of data (use `dput()`) that we can easily use to prototype possible graphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absent real data, this is the best I can come up with. No special packages required, just **ggplot2** and **plyr**:

```
#Some imagined data
dat <- data.frame(time = factor(rep(0:23,times = 20)),
                count = sample(200,size = 480,replace = TRUE),
                grp = sample(LETTERS[1:3],480,replace = TRUE))

head(dat)
  time count grp
1    0    79   A
2    1    19   A
3    2     9   C
4    3    11   A
5    4   123   B
6    5    37   A

dat1 <- ddply(dat,.(time,grp),summarise,tot = sum(count))

> head(dat1)
  time grp tot
1    0   A 693
2    0   B 670
3    0   C 461
4    1   A 601
5    1   B 890
6    1   C 580

ggplot(data = dat1,aes(x = time,y  = tot,fill = grp)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack") + 
    coord_polar()
```

[image]

I just coded the hours of the day as integers 0-23, and simply grabbed some random values for `Activity` counts. But this seems like it's generally what you're after.

**Edit**

A few more options based on comments:

```
#Force some banding patterns
xx <- sample(10,9,replace = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(time = factor(rep(0:23,times = 20)),
                day = factor(rep(1:20,each = 24),levels = 20:1),
                count = rep(c(xx,rep(0,4)),length.out = 20*24),
                grp = sample(LETTERS[1:3],480,replace = TRUE))
```

Options one using faceting:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x = time,y = day)) +
    facet_wrap(~grp,nrow = 3) + 
    geom_tile(aes(alpha = count))
```

[image]

Option two using color (i.e. fill):

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x = time,y = day)) +
    geom_tile(aes(alpha = count,fill = grp))
```

[image]

Comment: Great suggestion, but the added complication is Id like to see the trend changing over the year. This just captures 1 24 hour period, but Id like to see the 24 hours of 6 months of data.  Activgrams are these rasterized looking graphs of little dashes of data representing 1hr over 24 hr across the X then Day across the Y, and the program "darkens" the dash with increased activity, where Id like to now add in an additional parameter of food type

Comment: @Kerry I added some more options, but I want to stress once more that you really should put more effort into your question and be much more specific about your example data by providing us with something that exactly mirrors what you want to display. I normally wouldn't spend any time on a question like yours unless you provided more detail.

Comment: I thank you for spending so much time on my question then.  It is hard to describe what is needed without knowing the proper terms or even knowing where to start, other than with an image in my head of what I would "like".  I did not and still do not have the data in hand yet, just a hard copy of a piece of paper and knowledge of where I need to head.  You have given me a start and I sincerely appreciate your efforts!  Thank you